# Send data to bootstrap-notify from a backend code

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-notify

I am using a template that uses [bootstrap-notify](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) and I would like to send data to it from a view:

```
try:
    # things
except Exception as e:
    options = {
                    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign",
                    "title": "Bootstrap notify",
                    "message": "Turning standard Bootstrap alerts into 'notify' like notifications",
                    "url": "https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify",
                    "target": "_blank"
                }
    return JsonResponse(options)
```

In this example the message is showing but all the other options like "icon" and "title" are being ignored.

In JS, doing the same thing looks like:

```
$.notify({
// options
message: 'Hello World' ,
title: 'your title'
},{
// settings
type: 'danger'
});​
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the way that you are handling the `JsonResponse`? That may be the problem.

Comment: Please update with the code that is receiving that JsonResponse.  Your question is unanswerable otherwise.

Comment: What happens here `JsonResponse(options)`? Please share more details so that one can understand the problem

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing overridden your bootstrap-notify css? It would be very helpful if you can take a screenshot and show all messages in the console tab of browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like, let `http://localhost:8000/notify-options/`

```
$.get("http://localhost:8000/notify-options/", function(data, status){
    $.notify(data,{
        // settings
        type: 'danger'
    });​
});
```